# SWT/Jface Treeviewer to load tableviewer

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer, treeviewer

I am developing a small application. I am stuck in one of the scenario where I have to load data into table viewer after clicking `TreeViewer` item. Please suggest me way to handle this issue.

```
public void handleEvent(Event event) 
{
    TableViewer m_tableviewer.setData("Item Selected", event.item);
    // m_personViewer.setText(event.item + " was selected");
}
```

Comment: That is not valid Java syntax. Please elaborate and explain what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: For example when i click on button, it will load Tree. Now from Tree item...i i have to select one of the item will will again display Table related to tree item

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a `TableViewer` and not simply a `Table`? What kind of data does the `TableViewer` represent?

Comment: Prashant P you can edit your original post to add more information. It is easier for people to read and understand what you are trying to do. Please add all necessary details.

Comment: I want to use Table viewer and data is currently hard coded. But it will come from Form Textt field and stored in table.

Comment: I have query regarding SWT/Jface. We have multiple buttons (for eg... B1, B2, B3...). Each button on click will load tree items (using tree viewer), For example (B1->t1,B2->t2,B3->t3..etc). and these trees are loaded in single composite frame. 

So when i click on B1, it will display T1 tree viewer, but now i want to click on B2, T2 is not displayed. So my question is how can i dynimically change the tree viewer display on each button seperate click sitting in same composite.